# using System.Type as TSource, TTarget in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have to define a number of self mappings in AutoMapper, it's about 50+ mappings.

I have added them to a list

```
var alphabeticallySortedTypes = new List<Type>()
{
    typeof(AmtType),
    typeof(AnyCountType),
    //some more
}
```

And I try to add them inside a foreach:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateProfile("SelfCollectionMapping");
foreach(var alphabeticallySortedType in alphabeticallySortedTypes)
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<alphabeticallySortedType, alphabeticallySortedType> ()
    .WithProfile("SelfCollectionMapping")
}
```

The error I get is

alphabeticallySortedType is a variable but is used like a type.

Any idea on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the type objects as parameters to the CreateMap method.

```
Mapper.CreateMap(alphabeticallySortedType, alphabeticallySortedType);
```

Comment: I've defined an extension method public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapAllFieldsWhenTargetIsEmpty<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MappingExpression) that isn't accessible if I do that

Comment: You'll have to rewrite everything to work with the non generic interface.

Comment: The main thing is that from there I access ForAllMembers, that is not available using the non generic method

Comment: Yes it is, maybe you need to upgrade AM.